# IE11 showing <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "" }--> Error for *ngFor

Tags: angular7

I am trying to iterate through *ngFor using table tr td.*ngFor shows the empty data in IE browser.However works fine in chrome.

Piece of code:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let indx= index">
                        <td><strong>{{ item.name }}</strong></td>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            <mat-icon (click)="removeFile(indx)">delete</mat-icon>
                            <!-- <mat-icon>get_app</mat-icon> -->
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Can somebody answer this??

Comment: Is this is the piece of code which is not rendering? what about other components are they working properly in IE ?

Comment: yes.Other components rendering properly.Only this is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

[image]Okay,try with changing structure of table

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <th> <mat-icon (click)="removeFile(indx)">delete</mat-icon></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of files">
         <td><strong>{{ item.name }}</strong></td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay.. check your polyfills.ts file, I have added  image of polyfills file your file should be like this.